# Recurent error 502 Bad gateway Nginx Php5-fpm

Tags: php, nginx, debian, fpm

For some time we have regularly our site that crashes with the error "502 Bad Gateway". The server is with Nginx / Php5-Fpm.

During a crash, a "service php5-fpm restart" works to restart the site.

We have an web service, possibly linked to these crashes. We are not sure that this service is in question, and especially why this phenomenon.

Here are examples of logs, around the time we had a crash:

> Php5-fpm.log

```
[28-Nov-2016 22:12:13] NOTICE: [pool www] child 26227 exited with code 0 after 963.894198 seconds from start
[28-Nov-2016 22:12:13] NOTICE: [pool www] child 26820 started
[28-Nov-2016 22:12:33] NOTICE: [pool www] child 26226 exited with code 0 after 984.045707 seconds from start
[28-Nov-2016 22:12:33] NOTICE: [pool www] child 26826 started
[28-Nov-2016 22:28:57] NOTICE: [pool www] child 26826 exited with code 0 after 984.588029 seconds from start
[28-Nov-2016 22:28:57] NOTICE: [pool www] child 27322 started
[28-Nov-2016 22:33:17] WARNING: [pool www] server reached pm.max_children setting (5), consider raising it
[28-Nov-2016 22:34:30] WARNING: [pool www] server reached pm.max_children setting (5), consider raising it
[28-Nov-2016 22:38:11] WARNING: [pool www] server reached pm.max_children setting (5), consider raising it
[29-Nov-2016 01:18:37] NOTICE: [pool www] child 27773 exited with code 0 after 9848.051638 seconds from start
[29-Nov-2016 01:18:37] NOTICE: [pool www] child 651 started
```

According to research, I had seen [this](http://myshell.co.uk/blog/2012/07/adjusting-child-processes-for-php-fpm-nginx/).

I had tried to change settings, actually, the site did not seem to crash anymore but we sometimes had our server who had all its CPU at 100% for no reason for a while, then everything was back to normal.

Can our worries actually be resolved with these settings? If so, how do we configure it to no longer have these peaks at 100% CPU?

Thank you in advance.
Cordially.

Vincent Leveque